# Connect to model from view without going the viewmodel

Tags: xaml, mvvm

Currently I always make a copy in my ViewModel of what is created in my Model, which is then accessed by the view.

Is it possible in mvvm to skip the viewmodel part, when I know that nothing has to be done on what comes out of the model, because now it seems like lots of useless code just to pass from model to viewmodel to view. The model has INotifyPropertyChanged included (MVVM light version actually), is it possible to access the model from the xaml that composes the view directly?

Edit: i don't want to skip the viewmodel completely, just for some parts of the model.

Edit 2: To avoid things like this:

```
_GS.PropertyChanged += _GS_PropertyChanged; // hooking my vm up to my model
```

and then I just raise another propertychange when the eventhandler fires for that one in the VM. This just seems double code to me

```
if (e.PropertyName == "MoneyTypes")
{
   RaisePropertyChanged("MoneyTypes");
}
```

where MoneyTypes would then just be the following in the VM

```
classtype MoneyTypes 
{
    get { return model.MoneyTypes; }
}
```

Comment: You could just include the model data as a property of the viewmodel but it depends how rich your model is... in other words: this is a very difficult question to answer if you don't include details of what your view/viewmodel/model look like, what frameworks you are using etc etc - please provide more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objective of MVVM is to abstract the UI/View away from the logic - and this will not be broken by bindings which take this form:

```
{Binding ViewModel.Model.Property}
```

Doing this also means you are not copying properties from Model to ViewModel all the time.